# Identity 2.0 Custom UserManager/RoleManager vs razor calling User.IsInRole("RoleName")

Tags: asp.net-identity, iprincipal, isinrole

Questions are below: read through to see what you need to help answer...

I have

- VS 2013
- MVC 5 with Razor views
- Dapper DAL Custom UserManager and UserStore/User : IUser< int >

I build my own UserManager, RoleManager, UserStore, RoleStore, and all based on CustomUser : IUser< int > and CustomRole : IRole< int >

I can change passwords, recover forgotten passwords, login, logout... all works well.

However, in the razor view, when I try to use :

```
User.IsInRole("Administrators");
```

I get a SQL exception, (which probably happens in iPrincipal Identity class ???) from some other module:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  _HResult=-2146232060
  _message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  _doNotReconnect=false
  Class=20
  LineNumber=0
  Number=-1
  Server=""
  State=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  InnerException: <null>
```

But I can call

```
var user = AsyncHelpers.RunSync<CloudUser>(() => UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name));
ViewBag.IsInAdminRole = AsyncHelpers.RunSync<bool>(() => UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id, "Administrators"));
```

In my controller server code....

Questions:

1. What is the relationship between User.IsInRole and the UserManager/UserStore and/or RoleManager
2. How do I get User.IsInRole("Administrators") in the Razor View to 'understand' that it needs to use my custom Identity authentication implementation?

Comment: What do you see when you put `@User.GetType().ToString()` into view? i.e. what type is `User` under `IPrincipal`?

Comment: I know what you're thinking. I fixed this myself by deriving my own IPrincipal and WebView page. I used the solution here to fix my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366566/how-would-i-mimic-user-isinrole

Comment: Ah, that's good! Was half-way typing an answer, but you sorted it yourself!

Comment: Add your answer - I'll give you the points - I hate answering my own questions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your implementation does not provide `ClaimsPrincipal` when user is signed in.

`@User` should be `ClaimsPrincipal` and `IsInRole` ([see source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs#705)) does not reach into database, but rather checks for claims of type "Role" set on the principal's identity. If you see this exception, your IPrincipal is different form 'ClaimsPrincipal'.

I've read through the answer you linked and I don't think this is the best solution to use with Identity framework. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366566/how-would-i-mimic-user-isinrole) is pre-Identity and talks about MembershipProvider. You had to do these kind of things when you were dealing with MembershipProvider. Now Identity gives you much better and cleaner way to do custom functionality.

I would advise against implementing `CustomPrincipal` and use `ClaimsPrincipal` provided by the .Net framework. Just add Claims of type `ClaimTypes.Role` with role names on your principal when you return IPrincipal from your `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync`.

Comment: I'll give you the answer because I now derive from ClaimsPrincipal;  public class MyCustomPrincipal :  ClaimsPrincipal, IMyCustomPrincipal ...  but all that other code about CustomPrincipal was commented out in the link provided and I removed it anyway as I didn't need it. I even removed my implementation of IsInRole as that's already handled in ClaimsPrincipal. Thanks for the review on my stuff. Say, shouldn't there be a 'code review' section in here? lol

Comment: Good! glad it worked out and you did not have to use hacks. Regarding code review, there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but I never been there, so can't say if you'll find your uses there.